# POSTing media_ids to Twitter API with TwitterAPIExchange

Tags: php, twitter

I've tried almost every solution I could find - nothing is working. Basically, the status gets updated but the media_ids parameter gets ignored.

I'm using the TwitterAPIExchange.php library. Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';

$postfields = array(
    "media_ids" => 586556953049956353,

    "status" => "So we keep truly! testing!"
);

$requestMethod = 'POST';

echo $twitter->setPostfields($postfields)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();
```